# How to move object in Three.js (on mobile)

Tags: three.js, floor

Im working on [Blueprint3d](https://github.com/furnishup/blueprint3d) project, and have some issue. The issue is cannot drag and drop items on mobile web. Even if I try to drag some items its not working. tried to handle it but in THREE.Controls does not have drag drop function. Its similar with [this](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_draggablecubes) function that I want (you can think as cubes are items and sky is floor plan ). Whatever if its hard to handle, Could you point me function like keep the item when click once, and drop it to secondary clicked place. Best

Comment: Have a look at [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events).

Comment: I've checked it 100 times already, but its not what i want to use. just want like  keep item when click once, and item follow the touch cursor and after second click need to drop item.

Comment: _"and item follow the touch"_ What type of events do you plan to use to achieve this result then?

Comment: oh sorry I meant keep the item when click once, and drop it when secondary clicked place. @prisoner849